# msbuild, how to set environment variables?

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild

I am trying to set environment variables using project file (ex. .vcxproj)

I looked at property functions but it didn't seem to have such function.

I know there is a way to retrieve environment variable but couldn't find how to set it.

I feel like there should be way to set environment variables in project file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### If you are only using the variable in the context of MSBuild...

...then you can **use the standard MSBuild variables (aka properties)** instead of trying to set an environment variable. You can set properties when running msbuild using the [`/property` switch (aka `/p` switch)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022) (more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022)), as shown in the example below, which sets the `PublishProfile` property to the value `Debug` and the `VisualStudioVersion` property to the value `15.0`

```
   msbuild  Project.csproj /p:PublishProfile=Debug /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0
```

Find a list of the standard MSBuild's variables/properties [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452962/list-of-msbuild-built-in-variables)

You could also define arbitrary properties in the csproj file itself, using the `<PropertyGroup>` element. More on that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022#define-and-reference-properties-in-a-project-file)

### If you do need to set a true environment variable...

...well, it's not an out-of-box thing.  You **can write a custom task** and then leverage it in the project file. Here's a link to an MSDN thread that outlines how to do this:
[How to set envrionment variables in MSBuild file?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/0fb8d97d-513e-4d37-8528-52973f65a034) This example creates a new C# class `SetEnvVar` which inherits from the `Task` class ([`Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.utilities.task?view=msbuild-17-netcore)), in the `MSBuildTasks` namespace.

```
   //...
   using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
   using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

   namespace MSBuildTasks
   {
       public class SetEnvVar : Task
       {
           //...            
           public override bool Execute()
           {
               Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(_variable, _value);
               return true;
           }
```

... and then the task is invoked by this part of the `csproj` file:

```
      <UsingTask 
         TaskName="MSBuildTasks.SetEnvVar"
         AssemblyFile="$(RootDir)Tools\Bin\MSBuildTasks.dll"/>
```

Comment: Please include a code sample, links cannot be trusted

Answer (score 38):

The coded task can be put right at the project file since MSBuild v4.0. Like this:

```
<UsingTask
  TaskName="SetEnvironmentVariableTask"
  TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
  AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v$(MSBuildToolsVersion).dll">

  <ParameterGroup>
    <Name ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    <Value ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
  </ParameterGroup>

  <Task>
    <Using Namespace="System" />
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      <![CDATA[
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(Name, Value);
      ]]>
    </Code>
  </Task>

</UsingTask>
```

Note that in MSBuild 14+, the AssemblyFile reference should be just:

```
AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll"
```

The `SetEnvironmentVariableTask` can be then used from the target:

```
<Target Name="SampleTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <SetEnvironmentVariableTask Name="TEST_ENV_VAR" Value="$(MSBuildProjectName)" />
</Target>
```

That's much handier than authoring a separate .DLL for small MSBuild task(s).

Comment: Try as I might, I could not get this to work with Visual Studio 2012.  However, I was able to find a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886938/cannot-reference-dependency-assemblies-in-t4-template-when-using-transformonbuil/20688714#20688714).

Comment: This seems to work only within the context of a given target; when I tried to read the env var from another target it wasn't there anymore

Comment: Try Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(Name, Value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine) or Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(Name, Value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User). The default is Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(Name, Value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)

Comment: My experience was that although I could set it the environment variable I had to close/reopen VS2013 to have see the change.

Comment: Note that in MSBuild 14, the `AssemblyFile` reference should be just: `AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">`

Comment: The answer is to first invent the universe I see. This is *so* much more convenient than running an application from shell, and providing `SET Key="Value"` before starting the process.

Comment: If using msbuild on .NET core, you must use [RoslynCodeTaskFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-roslyncodetaskfactory) instead. It's available since MSBuild 15.8. Some tasks may work simply by replacing `CodeTaskFactory` with `RoslynCodeTaskFactory`.

Answer (score 13):

In the more recent versions of MS Build ([since 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task)), you can simply do this:

```
<Target Name="MyEnvironmentVariables">
    <Exec Command="A command that needs environment variables" EnvironmentVariables="HANDY_ENV_VAR_1=500;HANDY_ENV_VAR_2=A Useful Value"  />
</Target>
```

Make sure to separate the variables with a semicolon. You don't need a trailing semicolon though.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider writing the environment variables to a text file (.cmd) as a sequence of SET XXX=$(XXX) lines. Then execute the .cmd in the command window.

e.g. Define an ItemGroup with all the SET commands, then use Task 'WriteLinesToFile'  to write each item to a line in the .cmd text file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <BuildEnvItem Include="REM This file is auto generated. Do not edit" />
  <BuildEnvItem Include="SET TEST_ENV_VAR=$(TEST_ENV_VAR)" />
  <!-- add more as needed -->
<ItemGroup>

<Target Name="DefineBuildEnvironmentVariables">
    <WriteLinesToFile File="Build_env.cmd" Lines="@(BuildEnvItem)" Overwrite="true" Encoding="Unicode"/>
</Target>
```

This is may be useful in the situation where there is an existing .cmd that is using msbuild. The initial .cmd uses msbuild to generate the Build_env.cmd, and then calls Build_env.cmd before proceeding.