# How do environment variables know what environment I am running on and how do I set them in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, environment-variables

I am reading a selenium guidebook for c# and they show this:

```
class BaseTest
 {
 private static string VendorDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(
 System.AppContext.BaseDirectory).
 Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName
 + @"/vendor";
 protected IWebDriver Driver;
 public static string BaseUrl;
[SetUp]
 protected void SetUp()
 {
 BaseUrl = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BASE_URL") ??
"http://the-internet.herokuapp.com";
```

But it doesn't show how they are actually setting the environment variables.  Is BASE_URL coming from appsettings.json?  I'm not sure where they are getting it from.  Right now, I have a class with all of the urls I am using throughout my tests like this:

```
public static class Urls
{
    public static readonly string baseUrl = "https://localhost:5001/";
    public static readonly string aboutUrl = $"{baseUrl}about";
    public static readonly string citiesUrl = $"{baseUrl}cities";
    public static readonly string countriesUrl = $"{baseUrl}countries";
}
```

I don't think this is the best way to do it and want to try to use environment variables instead but I am not sure how to do that.  When I change from localhost to a production environment how I have it now will obviously break.  How can I set the baseUrl so it knows what environment I am in?

**EDITED**
My test solution is in a separate repo from my project solution.  My test solution is a c# xunit test project.  I added an appsettings.json file to my solution.  It looks like this

```
{
  "Base_Url": "https://testurl/",
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Inside one of my tests that uses the url, I am doing this

```
        public static IConfiguration InitConfiguration()
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
               .Build();
            return config;
        }
        [Fact]
        public void LoadFaqs()
        {
            using IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            var config = InitConfiguration();

            var faqurl = config["Base_Url"] + "faqs";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(faqurl);
         }
```

When I run my test, it is failing because it cannot find my appsettings.json file.  I also tried putting it inside my test folder and it still couldn't find it.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: As it is clearly seen from your snipper, baseUrl is hardcoded and is not an environment variable. If you have multiple classes like `Urls`, the proper one is most likely being injected in Startup, which forces it to use a certain `baseUrl` hardcoded in the class. I would recommend removing all `Urls` like classes and storing `baseUrl` in appsettings.json. For instance, you can set and then inject `IOptions<>` into the class that needs a certain url and build url link in the service class just like you do in `Urls`.

Comment: @Coke thank you for your response.  Would you be able to take a look at the edit I made to my post.  I tried to implement the appsettings.json and my test is unable to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locally, they must be setting them up by using either the project configuration (this is for Visual Studio):

```
Project properties -> Debug tab -> Environment variables
```

[image: Project properties -> Debug tab -> Environment variables]

or by running some MSBuild scripts/tasks on build events that ensure the environment variables are added. ([quick search on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267938/msbuild-how-to-set-environment-variables)). Or by adding them manually on the code when the test host is being built somehow (I'm guessing this is for some functional or integration testing)

In CI/CD pipelines they are set up depending on the platform you're using (Github, Gitlab, Azure DevOps etc)

The downside of using hard-coded classes for configuration is that whenever the configuration changes (like when you change your environment and instead of pointing to a local api you need to point to the production one), you need to change/recompile your code, like you said.

So yeah, I'd say have a look and explore those options. [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#evcp) can use several [configuration providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cp). On asp.net core, by default, they use one called [ChainedConfigurationSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.chainedconfigurationsource?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), which includes reading from the appsettings.json files, environment variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable are set by the Windows system with predefined values
the most common ENV variable is PATH
you can display env variables on cmd with: echo %ENV_NAME%
for example `echo %PATH%` gives you:

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
```

Env variables is a way to pass parameters between a parent process to a child process ( in the cases where args on command lines are a problem)
Then env context is only known by the child process and disappear once the process is killed.
Your selenium launcher might set additional variable with win api like:

```
public static void SetEnvironmentVariable (string variable, string? value);
```

[SetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=net-5.0)

In your example I would say: do not care about how selenium set this env variable , just take the content of BASE_URL ( hoping it is not empty....)