# How can I change the folder that Exec tasks in a csproj file generates its temporary exec.cmd files in?

Tags: msbuild, environment-variables, csproj

I have a .NET 6 project that includes some `Exec` nodes, and those commands are failing because (as in [this discussion on the msbuild repo](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/5168)) the paths of the generated `tmp<blah>.exec.cmd` files are not whitelisted.

The suggested fix in there is

> The location of this file is controlled by the environment variable
> `TEMP`. Can you set that to a custom value before invoking MSBuild?

Which I'm sure would work - but I don't know how to do that. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267938/msbuild-how-to-set-environment-variables) (which is for C++ not C#, but it's the best I can find) you can use `EnvironmentVariables="<blah>"` in that same node, but the files are still generated in %LOCALAPPDATA% despite my trying to set `TEMP` to something else. A failing example is below - what am I doing wrong?

```
<Target Name="ToolRestore" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="dotnet tool restore" StandardOutputImportance="high" EnvironmentVariables="TEMP=C:\MSBuildTemp" />
</Target>
```

An answer should ideally be valid for building/debugging in Visual Studio and via `dotnet build/test/publish`. Even better would be a method of making the value of `TEMP` be variable per-user, but that's not necessary.

Comment: If you change your Exec command to `echo %TEMP%` what does it print? That should indicate whether it's an msbuild or dotnet problem. Alternative simple solution: set TEMP in the shell itself and child processes (msbuild/VS/...) will inherit it.

Comment: @stijn I'll give it a shot, but I doubt `echo %TEMP%` will work either - I think the root of the problem is that the command is generated into a randomly-named .cmd file stored in `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Temp` and my employer requires items run from there to be on a whitelist. I *might* be able to get them to whitelist `tmp*.exec.cmd` or similar, but I doubt they'd be too happy with doing that. It took me long enough to get the EF Core tools whitelisted.

Comment: @stjin Nope, `echo %TEMP%` has the same thing happen. Setting UserProfile, AppDataLocal and/or Temp to a different location in the project file also has no effect. Setting the user-level environment variable has no effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [code for the Exec task](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/main/src/Tasks/Exec.cs#L197) it does use the standard `GetTempPath` function, which means it really should react to user-level environment variables. However that function is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=net-6.0&tabs=windows) like:

> This method checks for the existence of environment variables in the
> following order and uses the first path found:
>
> ```
> The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
> The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
> ...
> ```

so the suggested fix you found is not entirely correct: you might need `TMP` not `TEMP`. And indeed on my machine I have `TMP` set and msbuild uses it for its temporary batch files which can be seen using a target which prints the path of the batch file Exec uses:

```
<Target Name="TempTest">
  <Exec Command="echo %~dp0"/>
</Target>
```

Running on cmd.exe:

```
>set TMP=c:\temp

>msbuild temptest.proj /t:TempTest /v:m /nologo
  c:\temp\

>set TMP=c:\Users

>msbuild temptest.proj /t:TempTest /v:m /nologo
temptest.proj(7,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "
cmd.exe" could not be run. Failed to create a temporary file. Temporary files folder is full or its path is incorrect.
Access to the path 'c:\Users\tmpb31f9faffaab49e9b3bd5479a6823550.exec.cmd' is denied.
```

Comment: Yep, this works. A bit of a nuisance that I need to fiddle with environment variables after all, and not just change some option in the project, but such is life. Perhaps I can rally enough support over on Github that it becoms a configurable option. Thank you!

Comment: Yes it should ideally be configurable in another way; on the other hand, in 'defense' of msbuild: restricting a system such that it has problems writing to the temp directory is begging for problems.